# having trouble selecting an element's child with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selection, css-selectors

I have some nested elements as such:

```
<div id="knownID">
 <div class="knownClass">
   <span>
     <nobr>
       <span class="knownClass2">
         <span> ... </span>       <--- this keeps expanding deeper and deeper
         <span></span>            <--- this is the one I need!!!
       </span>
     </nobr>
   </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select this by doing...

```
$('#knownID span.knownClass2 span:nth-child(2)').html();
```

... but its not working out. How can I select that **2nd** `<span>` inside the `<span>` with `class="knownClass2"`? I've also tried...

```
$('#knownID > span.knownClass2 span:nth-child(2)').html();
```

... but it is returning null. I guess I'm not very familiar with how the nth-child() selector works in jQuery. Would someone mind explaining how it works as well as provide a possible solution to my problem?

Thanks,
Hristo

Comment: span:nth-child(2) should be correct.  Make sure "#equation > span.math span" works.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the fact that `#knownID` might not be on the DOM when I'm trying to do the above selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
$("#knownID span.knownClass2 > span:nth-child(2)").html();
```

This reads: Find the 2nd child of type span directly under a span whose class is "knownClass2" that is nested somewhere inside an element whose id is "knownId".

The documentation can be found here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

PS: Here is a context based solution as well:

```
$(" > span:eq(1)", "span.knownClass2", "div#knownID").html();
```

Comment: Absolutely!  If you end up not being able to depend on the #knownID div, then you can always remove that from the expression and the code will still work - it just won't be as secure because there might be other spans with a class of knownClass2 in the DOM.

Comment: So this is interesting... your solution works and I can accomplish what I want. But, Ramblingwood's solution also works in terms of selection but what I want to happen doesn't even though the selection works and I'm changing the same attributes.

Comment: You might be getting null as a response if the element does not have any data inside of it.  For example $("span.knownClass2").html() should return the HTML inside of span.knowClass2.  If there is no HTML inside of span.knownClass2 then the result will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) which gets the nth item in the jQuery object.  The list is zero indexed.

```
$("div#knownID span.knownclass2 span:eq(1)").html()
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/96RyH/1/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/96RyH/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$('#knownID')
    .children('div.knownClass')
    .children('span')
    .children('nobr')
    .children('span.knownClass2')
    .children('span:first')
    .next()
    .html();
```

Using explicit functions like this is faster than lumping them all together in a single string, as you've done.  This is because jQuery's selector engine works right to left.  Using functions like this will zero in on the ID element first, and then walk down to where you want to be.

**Why functions are faster**
jQuery uses the [Sizzle Selector Engine](http://sizzlejs.com/).  This engine is amazing, but one thing to note is that it works from right to left in a selector query.  What does that mean?  Take, for example, this jQuery snippet:

```
$('#foo a.bar');
```

Sizzle will first find every anchor on the page that has the class `bar`, and then check each one to see if it is an ancestor of the element with id `foo`.  This is not optimized, especially if there are many anchor tags on the page.  Sizzle must do it this way because it doesn't know explicitly what you are intending to find.

This, however:

```
$('#foo').children('a.bar');
```

Will first find the element with id `foo`, and then step down one level to the anchors with class `bar`.  It's much faster.  You can tell jQuery do this, because you have foreknowledge of your DOM structure.

Comment: Its funny jQuery's slogan is "Write less do more" ...This code seems to show the opposite. Also OP was asking to get the second span not the first.

Comment: This approach is also very dependent on the unnamed elements of div.knownClass, span and nobr between the IDed div#knownID element and span.knownClass2.  This makes the code more prone to bugs if the DOM changes.

Comment: Sorry.  For *my* web applications, **`Speed is King`**.  In what case would you change the DOM and not update the JavaScript that accesses it, anyway?

Comment: No sense in arguing... but I would appreciate an explanation as to why your approach is faster than the other? Is it due to parsing the string?

Comment: Explanation provided.  Let me know if it needs further clarification.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much maintenance overhead you are willing to incur.  You could always simply provide some context to speed up your selectors, without having to traverse as many elements and still keep your code clean:

$(" > span:eq(1)", "span.knownClass2", "div#knownID").html();

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but seriously:  Anyone who makes a case against speed always goes for the "more maintenance" argument.  But that doesn't make any sense.  Using an explicit jQuery chain of child selectors does not cause the developer to incur ongoing maintenance.  Does he have to update his JavaScript **if** he changes this particular structure in his DOM?  Yes.  But that's more apt to happen in development anyway.  And if it does happen farther down the road, it is trivial to adjust the JavaScript right along with the DOM changes.  Not to mention my chain is far more readable.

Comment: I think you make very good points Stephen.  I don't think there is only one correct solution, but preferences on the approach to take.

Comment: @Pan, On that note, we definitely agree. :)

Comment: Hmmm...  not to beat a dead horse, but I liked your context example in the comments above.  *Until* I just read this in the documentation:  "Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`"  For the sake of completeness, I need to mention that `.find()` is a very slow function, as it must search every single child element to discover the requested elements.

Comment: @Stephen - that's definitely true.  It's just a good way to limit the scope of your search. For example, if you have many elements that match the remainder of the selector, but only a single one that matches the context then this can provide a performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
$("#knownID .knownClass .knownClass2 span:nth-child(2)")
```

See the JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/opoji3/edit

Maybe you have an error elsewhere?

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the fact that `#knownID` might not be on the DOM when I'm trying to do the above selection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `>` between `knownClass2` and the `nth-child` thing like this:

```
$('#knownID  span.knownClass2 > span:nth-child(2)').html();
```

Comment: I believe this will return nothing as there is no direct decendent of span.knownclass2 from parent #knownID

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

`$("span.KnownClass2").children(":last").html();`

Comment: Although this is valid, it would be very slow if there were many `span` elements on the page.  Especially in IE.

Comment: This would also not work if you wanted the 2nd element and not the last one.